# Couldn't find type java.sql.Date. Are you missing a dependency on your classpath?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying to run my application in Spring Boot using MongoDB with spring-data but I can't because IntelliJ shows me this error during build:

> Error:java: Couldn't find type java.sql.Date. Are you missing a
>   dependency on your classpath?

I'm using mongo java driver version 3.8.2, spring boot 2.1 and project is in Java 11. I have no idea what is wrong here could someone help me please?

Comment: could you provide your  pom.xml?

Answer (score 6):

Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven/Gradle -> Runner -> tic on "Delegate IDE build/run actions"

Comment: I can't use Intellij to run individual tests anymore with this. Though this does fix it.

Answer (score 3):

the problem came from this settings:
[image]

Please uncheckUser'--release' option for cross-compilation(Java 9 and later), it's a common source of problem with the library Date

Answer (score 2):

IDEA > File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors

- click/select the module in which you're encountering the troubles (middle part of the settings window)
- ensure "Obtain processors from project classpath" is ticked (unselect custom "Processor path" option)